# Is there any kind of dependency concept in Grails Interceptors like in Grails Filters?

Tags: grails

In Grails version prior to 3.0, there is `dependsOn` keyword that defines dependency of One filter on another. Is there any kind of dependency mechanism for Interceptors? I am upgrading grails from 2.x to 3.x where i needed to upgrade a filter that contains `dependsOn` and has dependency of other filter.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any kind of dependency mechanism for Interceptors?

Yes.

Interceptors support an `order` property which affects the order in which interceptors are executed.  You can make one interceptor run before or after another by assigning the `order` property relative to another interceptors `order` property.

See http://docs.grails.org/3.3.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptorOrdering for more info.